# Devise not storing sessions and losing credentials after redirect

Tags: session, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, warden

It is a VERY strange bug and I am leading with it for 24 hours. It was working well and suddenly it started to fail.

The problem:
When I want to login with Facebook, the app redirec to Facebook permissions request, go back, save the update in the account model (access_token, and updated_at), but I am redirected to the home without permissions to access to signed_in sections.

My stack is:
Rails4, Devise 3.0.0.rc, Omniauth, Omniauth-facebook 1.4.0.
The app only accept login with Facebook.

Take a look:

**Omniauth controller**:  account_signed_in? = true

```rb
class Accounts::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @account = Account.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_account)

    if @account.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @account, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      puts account_signed_in? # <-- true
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_account_registration_url
    end
  end
```

**ApplicationController**:  account_signed_in? = true

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private
    def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
      nil
    end

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      puts account_signed_in? # <-- true
      current_account.pages.empty? ? new_page_path : pages_path
    end
```

**StaticController** (home) account_signed_in? = false

```rb
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def home
    puts account_signed_in? # <- false
    render layout: 'home'
  end
```

I don't know if can there be something that disturb the normal flow of sessions between Devise and Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Found that!

The sessions weren't saved because of the domain parameter in session_store.rb:

```rb
BrainedPage::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  key: '_my_session', :domain => Rails.configuration.domain
```

Seems I had changed the domain configuration in development environment (added port, because I was using this var for other propose too), and I didn't realize the impact it could make.